# jPlayer circle-player demo includes a css link not contained in the distribution

Tags: css, jplayer

This follows off a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702592/jplayer-circle-player-does-not-show-circle-first-time-around-with-wav-files-made).

While trying to put together a simplified application that showed the problem, I went back to the demo which does not show the problem.  I tried using this as a model for my simplified demo, when I was brought up short by line 11 of the source of [the demo](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-05/):

```
<link href="/css/jPlayer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

They are including a root-level stylesheet that is not available in either the latest [jPlayer](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer) or [Circle-Player](https://github.com/maboa/circleplayer) distributions.

So what is this jPlayer.css and where can I get it?  The only idea I have is using one of the skin-flavored jplayer css files.

I am thinking that NOT including this in my application is the reason for the problem I was having with the circle player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is a stylesheet for the site jplayer.org, not the player. It is not required for jPlayer Circle Player to function. It is definitely not the source of the problem you have described in your other question.